# Elastic Beanstalk cron and deployment permissions

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

During deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk I want to do two things:

1. Take a file with cron entries and place this file in /etc/cron.d/
2. Change the file permissions on shell scripts contained in a single directory so they can be executed by the cron

In my .ebextensions folder I have the following:

```
container_commands:
  00fix_script_permissions:
    command: "chmod u+x /var/app/current/scripts/*"
  01setup_cron:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/propel_mis_crons.txt > /etc/cron.d/propel_mis_crons && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/propel_mis_crons"
    leader_only: true
```

And the propel_mis_crons.txt in the .ebextensions folder has:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
MAILTO="dev@23sparks.com"
* * * * * root /var/app/current/scripts/current_time.sh
```

I've checked the deploy logs and I can see the following:

```
2013-08-09 14:27:13,633 [DEBUG] Running command 00fix_permissions_dirs
2013-08-09 14:27:13,633 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command 00fix_permissions_dirs
<<< 
2013-08-09 14:27:13,736 [DEBUG] No test for command 00fix_permissions_dirs
2013-08-09 14:27:13,752 [INFO] Command 00fix_permissions_dirs succeeded
2013-08-09 14:27:13,753 [DEBUG] Command 00fix_permissions_dirs output: 
2013-08-09 14:27:13,753 [DEBUG] Running command 01setup_cron
2013-08-09 14:27:13,753 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command 01setup_cron
<<<
2013-08-09 14:27:13,829 [DEBUG] Running test for command 01setup_cron
2013-08-09 14:27:13,846 [DEBUG] Test command output: 
2013-08-09 14:27:13,847 [DEBUG] Test for command 01setup_cron passed
2013-08-09 14:27:13,871 [INFO] Command 01setup_cron succeeded
2013-08-09 14:27:13,872 [DEBUG] Command 01setup_cron output:
```

However on deployment the permissions on all files in the scripts directory are not set correctly and the cron does not run. I'm not sure if the cron not running isn't running because of the permissions issue or if there is something else preventing this. This is running on a PHP5.4 64-bit Amazon Linux instance.

Would appreciate some assistance on this. It's quite possible that over time new shell scripts to be triggered by a cron will be added.

Answer (score 3):

```
container_commands:
00_fix_script_permissions:
command: "chmod u+x /opt/python/ondeck/app/scripts/*"
```

I'm a Linux and AWS Noob, however I found that modifying your command as above did succeed for my use case.

/opt/python/current/app/scripts/createadmin now has execute permission for the user

Comment: you have saved me! The key is to edit the .../ondeck/... file, not the .../current/... one! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

@Ed seems to be correct where he suggests chmod'ing the `ondeck` file as opposed to the `current` one.

Additionally, this is how I setup my cron jobs through the elastic beanstalk .config file. It certainly might not be the *best* way, but it works for my application.

```
`"files":{
    "/home/ec2-user/cronjobs.txt":{
        "mode":"000777",
        "owner":"ec2-user",
        "group":"ec2-user",
        "source":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxx/cronjobs.txt"
    }
}
"container_commands":{
    "01-setupcron":{
     "command": "crontab /home/ec2-user/cronjobs.txt -u ec2-user",
     "leader_only": true
    },`
```

First, I pull in a cronjobs text file and save it in the ec2-user folder. Next, in the container_commands I apply that file to the crontab.

Again, I'm no expert, but that's the best I could come up with and it has worked pretty well for us.