# Change file permissions using elasticbeanstalk config file

Tags: linux, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application which is launched through AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Git. I recently learned about their config files and some of the actions you can perform with them.

I have some files which need to have specific permissions. When I do a `git aws.push` the permissions are changed.

One of the files is called,say `foo.inc.php` it's owner:group is `webapp:webapp` it's default permissions are `666`. I want the permissions to be `644`.

Here's what I have in my `elb.config` file:

```
"container_commands":{
  "05-setperms":{
     "command": "chmod 664 /var/app/current/baz/foo.inc.php"
    },
  "06-setperms":{
     "command": "find /var/app/current/baz -name foo.inc.php -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;"
    },
  "07-setperms":{
     "command": "find /var/app/current/baz -name foo.inc.php -exec chmod 644 {} \;"
    },
}`
```

(I left out commands which are working(starting cron jobs, etc))

These three commands are very similar, yet none of them seem to work. After the push and the environment update, the file is back to `666`.

What can I do differently? I have other applications that could benefit from automatic permissions being set so I would really like to learn what's going wrong and how to fix it.

I'm on a Linux environment.
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547516/windows-setting-php-file-permissions-before-deploying-to-amazon-beanstalk) question and borrowed some of the code.
The sparse AWS documentation is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Found it! 
Thanks to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184364/elastic-beanstalk-cron-and-deployment-permissions) by [Ed Campion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401929/ed-campion) I got it working.

If you edit the `/var/app/ondeck/file.ext` it works!

Your file is `ondeck` as opposed to `current`